# -Wunused-variable warning

Tags: c++, warnings

I am implementing the singleton design pattern in a school assignment, and this is my class header file:

```
class Scheduler {
public:
    static Scheduler * instance();
    ~Scheduler();

private:
    Scheduler();
};

static Scheduler * _singleton = 0; // WARNING HERE
```

My problem is that I keep getting this error:

```
../Scheduler.h:60:20: warning: ‘_singleton’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
```

And we have to submit assignments with no compilation warnings. How do I get rid of this warning? There's no need for me to use `_singleton` in the header file itself so I'm not sure what to do. I know it's stupid, but still...

Ideas?

Comment: You aren't trying to compile the header file, are you?

Comment: remove the line that reports the error?

Comment: Who wrote the header, you or the teacher?  If you did it, remove the declaration of the `_singleton` from the header; it would limit you to one Scheduler per source file, not one Scheduler, period.  If the teacher did it and you can't modify it, then you're stuck with asking him how to get rid of the warning, I think.

Comment: Was the answer useful at all, or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 4):

Your static singleton instance pointer should be a class member. Currently it is just a free pointer.

```
class Scheduler {
// as before
private:
    Scheduler();
    static Scheduler* _singleton; // declare it in the class
};
```

and in the implementation file:

```
Scheduler * Scheduler::_singleton = 0;
```

Comment: Definition of `_singleton` should not be `static` and should be moved to `cpp` file also.

Comment: @Lol4t0 ah sorry, I misread your comment. I thought you meant the pointer shouldn't be static :-)